# C# reflection, lambda?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I need to do this using reflection:

```
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<MyType>)list).Columns(columns =>
           {
                 columns.Add(foo => foo.Title)
                        .Titled("Custom column title")
                        .SetWidth(110);
                 columns.Add(foo => foo.Description)
                        .Sortable(true);
           }).WithPaging(20)
```

Now I have `var g` which is object created after call `@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<Type>)Model)` using reflection. This is done by reflection because list contains object of class created at runtime and I need to call Grid(list) with defined type(which didn't exist at compile time):

```
var method = typeof(GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions).GetMethods()
                        .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Grid")
                        .ElementAt(0)
                        .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t });
var g = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { Html, list });
```

So I need do something like:

```
g.Columns(columns =>
               {
                     columns.Add(foo => foo.Title)
                            .Titled("Custom column title")
                            .SetWidth(110);
                     columns.Add(foo => foo.Description)
                            .Sortable(true);
               }).WithPaging(20)
```

using reflection.

`var g` is type of HtmlGrid:

> https://github.com/leniel/Grid.Mvc/blob/master/GridMvc/Html/HtmlGrid.cs

**Can someone provide example code to do this?**

---

To be on the safe side I am adding Grid.Mvc github link:
https://github.com/leniel/Grid.Mvc/blob/master/GridMvc/ because I don't know the way to solve it

Comment: Can you give more information about *why* you're trying to call this by reflection? Assuming this is GridMvc, I can only see a *property* called Columns rather than a method anyway... can you give a reference to the type you're using?

Comment: Can't you just cast `g` to the correct type and call the method normally?

Comment: How do you know that the type `t` has a `Title` and a `Description` properties?

Comment: Because doing it fully through reflection gets quite ugly. The `foo => foo.Title` will have to be built through Expression trees.

Comment: @xanatos Can you indicate me how do you mean it? Some example?

Comment: @mrfazolka Changed my response. It seems that `Add` has an overload with `PropertyInfo`

Answer (score 1):

Third time is the charm :)

This time I tested it.

You use it like

```
@Html.MakeGrid(items, someType)
```

where `someType` is the `Type` of your objects.

or even

```
this.Write(Helper.MakeGrid(Html, items, someType);
```

or in any way you would use your @Html.Grid method.

I cheat twice: once I call through reflection from the non-generic `MakeGrid` a generic `MakeGridInternal`, and the second time in `CreateColumns` where I use reflection to get the `PropertyInfo` of the various columns.

Note that when calling `MakeGrid` you must pass the real type of your elements in `type`, and `items` must be a collection of any reference type (but 90% it will work if you change the signature to `object items`)

```
public static class Helper {
    public static IHtmlString MakeGrid(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<object> items, Type type) {
        // You can give even this signature:
        // public static IHtmlString MakeGrid(HtmlHelper html, object items, Type type)
        // But clearly items MUST be a collection of some type!
        return (IHtmlString)typeof(Helper).GetMethod("MakeGridInternal").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { html, items });
    }

    public static IHtmlString MakeGridInternal<T>(HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class {
        return GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid<T>(html, items)
                 .Columns(CreateColumns)
                 .WithPaging(10);
    }

    public static void CreateColumns<T>(IGridColumnCollection<T> columns) {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        PropertyInfo title = t.GetProperty("Title");
        PropertyInfo description = t.GetProperty("Description");

        columns.Add(title)
            .Titled("MyTitle")
            .SetWidth(100);

        columns.Add(description)
            .Sortable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's nice idea, thanks. I will try it after weekend :)

Comment: Hmm.....I get error: property is not defined for type Int32 id system.object.
Is possible to fix it some easy way?:)

Comment: @mrfazolka Sadly no I think

Comment: Ok, don't, never mind :) I have backup solutiom :) I have backup solution :)

Comment: @mrfazolka Try now :-) I thought about the problem, installed the MVC and solved it